# How to create an Rmarkdown distill article that links directly to URL

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown, r-distill

I would like to link directly to a URL (say, http://www.stackoverflow.com) for a particular distill article post. Is it possible to do this somewhere in the YAML? Somewhere else?

```
---
title: "Untitled"
description: |
  A new article created using the Distill format.
author:
  - name: Nora Jones 
    url: https://example.com/norajones
    affiliation: Spacely Sprockets
    affiliation_url: https://example.com/spacelysprokets
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: distill::distill_article
---
```

I have tried passing `url` to the `output` parameter and a few alternatives but remain unsuccessful.

**Why would I want to do this?**
I would like to leverage the listing page and categories features from distill, but I do not have the need to have an actual "article" underneath the content. Rather, I want the listing page to serve a direct link (hyperlink) to a different page/site/application. So we retain all the benefits of "post" on a listing page -- of tagging, a preview picture, and a short description -- but I do not have the need to link to an actual post, just a launch point.

---

NOTE: I am not interested in *embedding* via an iframe or `knitr::include_url` or `htmltools::includeHTML`. I would like to go directly to the resulting page. Think a gallery of shiny apps or existing applications / HTML documents, maybe bookdown books -- think like a "catalog", discovery page, bookmark collection, similar to RStudio's [connectwidget package](https://rstudio.github.io/connectwidgets/).

Answer (score 0):

You can publish the Webpage directly to [Rpubs.com](https://rpubs.com) Where it is hosted for free, with it's own unique URL so you can share the results. You will have to click the "Publish" button in the top left corner of your viewer Pane, and create an account, but its definitely worth it!

[image]

Here is me publishing your code to my Rpubs account with it's own URL
[image]

Comment: Thank you, however, this is not relevant to my question. I will work on making my question more clear. I am looking for a way to still leverage "posts" from blogdown/distill, but have them be direct links to apps or other web pages when someone clicks on them from their rendered listing page.